# Null body in awk vs. gawk

Tags: macos, awk

ENVIRONMENT: MacOS, awk/gawk available, home-brew installed.

I'm developing an awk script that eventually came to rely on gawk (specifically, the `asort()` function). In moving to gawk, I noticed something unexpected:

The body of the script is null; there are only `BEGIN{}` and `END{}` blocks, but nothing in the body. The reason is that the script does not respond to line-by-line input from an external source. Instead, it is used to read three different files and take action on those files.

Under awk, I was able to specify

`awk -f dbchk.awk`

and it ran fine. But using

`gawk -f dbchk.awk`

it executes the `BEGIN{}` block and then hangs waiting for stdin. I can use

`echo "" |gawk -f dbchk.awk`

and it runs fine, but that seems kind of klutzy. Is there a way to instruct gawk to ignore stdin and just jump to the `END{}` block?

---

@markp-fuso As to the question of *why*, the project is a DB consistency checker that uses two unordered lists, keyed by a UUID string, that must be sorted before a check can be made. Checks go both ways: is key(A) in set(B), is key(B) in set(A), and so on. The third list is a filter that allows a subset of entries to be checked for brevity.

Since the `set(A) :: set(B)` relationship check goes both ways, there is no logical hierarchy to pass in a list of records using the traditional gawk method.

gawk ended up being the best tool to code this in, at least for me. Bash ended up with a horrible mishmash of greps/seds/awks/trs and more, and was taking forever. gawk is much faster and has everything I need. Python may be a better choice but I wanna get this done and I've spent too much time on it already. And besides, I want to be a better gawker!

I'd post the whole thing but it's pretty messy right now. And thanks again for what seems like a really obvious answer.

Comment: please update the question with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); in this case it may also help if you update the question with the output from `awk --version` and `gawk --version`

Comment: if there is no 'body' to the `awk` script then consider combining the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks into a single `BEGIN` block; another work around would be a do-nothing 'body', eg, `BEGIN {...} FNR==1 { next } END {...}`; another alternative to feed a 'dummy' file: `BEGIN {...} END {...}` <<< ""`

Comment: having said that ... having hard time coming up with a valid reason for an `awk` script that processes multilpe files but doesn't do anything with the actual data in the files; what you mean by *`it is used to read three different files and take action on those files.`* ... since you're not really 'reading' the files and exactly what 'action' are you performing on the files? ... so, back to the request to provide a minimal, reproducible example ...

Comment: @markp-fuso Your second comment, omission of the END block, solved it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to instruct gawk to ignore stdin and just jump to the
> END{} block?

You might use `exit` in `BEGIN`'s action for that purpose, it is described in [The GNU Awk User's Guide - Exit Statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html) following way

> When an `exit` statement is executed from a `BEGIN` rule, the program
> stops processing everything immediately. No input records are read.
> However, if an `END` rule is present, as part of executing the `exit`
> statement, the `END` rule is executed(...)

Simple example

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "I am BEGIN";exit}{print "This will be skipped"}END{print "I am END"}'
```

gives output

```
I am BEGIN
I am END
```

also if you would provide input files after that.

> MacOS

I do not have access to that, please test my example at your machine and write if behavior is as desired.

Answer (score 2):

GNU Awk is behaving in a [POSIX-conforming](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) manner:

> *If an awk program consists of only actions with the pattern BEGIN, and the BEGIN action contains no getline function, awk shall exit without reading its input when the last statement in the last BEGIN action is executed. If an awk program consists of only actions with the pattern END or only actions with the patterns BEGIN and END, the input shall be read before the statements in the END actions are executed.*

To avoid the input scanning loop from activating, you must have only `BEGIN` clauses, no `END` clauses.

Awk skip the input loop and jump to your `END` block if you rename it to `BEGIN`:

```
BEGIN { /* first do this */ }
BEGIN { /* then do this, and we are done */ }
```

Comment: run this :::: `pv "$anyfile" | gawk -p- -be 'END { print "END { }", NR, FNR, NF, ERRNO, +_ } BEGIN { print "BEGIN { }", NR, FNR, NF, ERRNO; exit } { ++_ }'` :::::::: An instant `exit` statement also bypasses consuming anything from `/dev/stdin`, as corroborated by the 0 byte count of `pv`

Answer (score 1):

While it is functionally no better than

```
echo "" |gawk -f dbchk.awk
```

I prefer the look of this:

```
gawk -f dbchk.awk /dev/null
```

It's effectively self-documenting, and works fine.

```
$: gawk 'BEGIN{print "BEGIN"}END{print "END"}' /dev/null
BEGIN
END

$: echo 'BEGIN{print "BEGIN"}END{print "END"}'>foo
$: gawk -f foo /dev/null
BEGIN
END
```

Or if you want to simplify your call a bit,

```
$: cat foo
#! /bin/sh
exec gawk 'BEGIN{print "BEGIN"}END{print "END"}' /dev/null

$: ./foo
BEGIN
END
```

The `exec` isn't really necessary. It just replaces the call to `sh` on the stack after the input redirection is done.